# Dividing numbers on an FPGA

Tags: fpga, programmable-logic, arithmetic-division

I wrote a program for a Cyclone II FPGA that divides 2 64 bit numbers and returns if the remainder is 0 using the modulus (%) operation.

When I compiled the program with 64 bit numbers for the divisor and dividend it used almost all of the logic cells in the device.

Is there a way to do division, or modulus, or [if modulus==0] in a way that uses less logic cells?

Comment: Backup and talk about the actual problem you are trying to solve - chances are this is not the most efficient way to do it!

Comment: It is more just a general question.  I was thinking about using an FPGA as a math accelerator to do complex operations.

Comment: Division is not a nice operation to try to perform in a single clock cycle. I'm a bit surprised that you actually got that to synthesize, not all synthesizers even support division for synthesis.

Comment: Is there a way I can split it into multiple clock cycles so that I can get a net increase in the number of divisions I can do?  What I mean is that if I split it into 4 clock cycles, It could do more than 4 divisions simultaneously.

Comment: ChrisStratton the project I am currently doing is determining if a 64 bit number is prime but want general answers for division.

Comment: In practice for this kind of thing you'll find it surprisingly hard to beat a CPU's integer divide unit unless you apply some kind of clever non-general technique. Or find a suitable IP block. The device has a lot of embedded *multipliers*, so you may be able to use some sort of Newton-Raphson technique to find the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Our Open-Source PoC-Library has a multi-cycle division IP core, which can be synthesized as a pipeline. The bit count of the dividend and divisor as well as the radix can be configured to the users needs. This module returns the quotient as well as the remainder.

```
entity arith_div is
  generic (
    A_BITS             : positive;          -- Dividend Width
    D_BITS             : positive;          -- Divisor Width
    RAPOW              : positive := 1;     -- Power of Compute Radix (2**RAPOW)
    PIPELINED          : boolean  := false  -- Computation Pipeline
  );
  port (
    -- Global Reset/Clock
    clk : in std_logic;
    rst : in std_logic;

    -- Ready / Start
    start : in  std_logic;
    ready : out std_logic;

    -- Arguments / Result (2's complement)
    A : in  std_logic_vector(A_BITS-1 downto 0);  -- Dividend
    D : in  std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0);  -- Divisor
    Q : out std_logic_vector(A_BITS-1 downto 0);  -- Quotient
    R : out std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0);  -- Remainder
    Z : out std_logic  -- Division by Zero
  );
end arith_div;
```

See the source of [PoC.arith.div](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_div.vhdl) for the full implementation (it's too long to post it here).

Answer (score 3):

Do you know anything about the divisor? If you do, then there are several things that can be done.

- If the divisor \$m=2^k\$ is a power of 2, then $$\mathbb{mod}(x, m)=0\iff x \& (2^k-1)=0 $$.
- If the divisor is a known constant, then there's several tricks, see: http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf and https://hal.inria.fr/ensl-00642145/PDF/LUTConstDiv.pdf

The clue to solving division, in general, is Euclidian Division. Read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division to get an understanding of why pipelining this algorithm is necessary. It basically boils down to the same algorithm you would use to solve division by hand.